# Libgdx Android Game Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, multithreading, libgdx, fatal-error, segmentation-fault

I have developed a game using Libgdx. It stops randomly by giving Fatal signal 11(SIGSEGV) error. Sometimes it force closes and sometimes force closes and then automatically restarts. The logs printed during force close are:-

```
A/libc(3475): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 3534 (Thread-343)
```

I also keep on getting some logs during my game play from time to time.

```
04-27 09:04:18.750: D/dalvikvm(3475):   Issue registerizing the trace in the backend.
04-27 09:04:18.750: I/dalvikvm(3475): Ignoring other issues and retrying without backend registerization
04-27 09:04:18.750: D/dalvikvm(3475): JIT_INFO: Retrying trace Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFontCache;translate, offset 40


04-27 09:12:39.410: D/dalvikvm(3475): JIT_INFO: Issues while compiling trace  Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 7
04-27 09:12:39.410: D/dalvikvm(3475):   The trace provoked a spill.
04-27 09:12:39.410: I/dalvikvm(3475): Trying less registerization from 1 to 0
04-27 09:12:39.410: D/dalvikvm(3475): JIT_INFO: Retrying trace Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 7


04-27 09:14:08.930: I/dalvikvm(3475): JIT_INFO: Overwriting association of v6:ecx with xmm0


04-27 09:18:30.610: D/dalvikvm(3475): JIT_INFO: Issues while compiling trace  Ljava/util/Arrays;fill, offset 5
04-27 09:18:30.610: D/dalvikvm(3475):   The trace provoked a spill.
04-27 09:18:30.610: I/dalvikvm(3475): Trying less registerization from 1 to 0
```

Please help me I am stuck and not able to find the cause of issue.

Comment: Do you use lambda? android requires compatibility with java 7, any java8 code will result on an error under android platform.

Comment: No, I am using java 7.

Comment: Are you using separate threads on the project?

Comment: After long debugging for nearly 2 complete days. I found that I was creating body in draw() in one of by inherited Actor. When body was creating when game was started it was creating problems, now I delayed body creation and now everythng is working fine. I am calling super.draw() and super.act() from my render method of stage, still I don't know how could this be problem of thread or updating on UI thread (Gdx.app.postRunnable()).

Comment: In short didn't get the reason, just found the line of error and modified it.

Comment: you should never create anything on render methods ^-^

Comment: I think render() works on update thread, so we can do that.